# How to deal with broad and heavy Elastic Search index

Tags: elasticsearch, join, lucene, elastic-stack, elk

I have fat ElasticSearch index with plenty of fields. I'd like to enrich this index with another field containing arrays of 1024 dimensionality. However, I find it way too much.

Thus, I'm curious if it is possible to perform queries on both of indices as if they were single index effectively. It is important to notice that both of supposed indices do not have the same mappings but could be joined via user_id field.

Or is there better solution to deal with broad indices?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no JOINs in Elasticsearch; though this is about to change — more runtime lookups (coming in [8.2 as a preview](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/runtime-retrieving-fields.html#lookup-runtime-fields)) than full-blown JOINs for now though.

The closest thing in a stable release right now are [index-time lookups](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html), but that won't solve your issue. So I'm afraid you'll need application-side JOINs.

PS: "I find it way too much" is for disk space or what is too much around index-time enrichments?

Comment: actually both. With 1 shard it is going to take ~1Tb of memory to store all the arrays I need

Comment: I'm wondering if 1 shard is the right solution here. Also, there might be tweaks in the mapping possible depending on how you need to access that array?

Comment: Nope, 1 shard is not the right solution) it was a test flight

Comment: by the way, was the correct link attached?

Comment: For index-time lookups? Yes. BTW [runtime lookups are coming in 8.2 as a preview](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/runtime-retrieving-fields.html#lookup-runtime-fields) — so very soon this could solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are you looking for is an [Elasticsearch alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/aliases.html).

Aliases allow you to effectively join two indices at search which behaves like if you have only one. This can be useful to search something accross two indices when you have a common field in two of them.

Comment: will have a look and test it, will come back later with feedback) thanks!

Comment: so far as I understand ES alias is NOT the solution for me. It works more as union with some filters rather than join with filters.